# Computing ${\mathcal Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_D, \mathcal{O}_X)$, where $D\subset X$ is a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth scheme and $D\subset X$ be a divisor on $X$. I want to compute the sheaves ${\mathcal Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_D, \mathcal{O}_X)$. Actually it is quite easy. We have the following locally free resolution of $\mathcal{O}_D$:
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\stackrel{\varphi}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_D\to0.$$
Applying ${\mathcal Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\_,\mathcal{O}_X)$ to the complex
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\stackrel{\varphi}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to0$$
we obtain the complex
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_X\stackrel{\varphi^*}\to\mathcal{O}_X(D)\to0,$$
so ${\mathcal Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_D,\mathcal{O}_X)=\text{ker}\,\varphi^*$, ${\mathcal Ext}^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_D, \mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_X/\text{im}\,\varphi^*$.

Now, to finish the computations, how can I prove the injectivity of $\varphi^*$?

As Mariano Suárez-Alvarez suggested I can check it locally. Let $\varphi:I\to A$ be an inclusion of an ideal to the ring, where $I$ is prime ideal of codimension one. I have a map $$\varphi^*:Hom_A(A,A)→Hom_A(I,A)$$ which acts by sending $f\in Hom_A(A,A)$ to $\varphi^*(f):=f\circ\varphi∈Hom_A(I,A)$. To prove that $\varphi^*$ is an injection we need to check that $f\circ\varphi=0$ implies $f=0$. The condition $f\circ\varphi=0$ gives that $f(I)=0$. The last condition implies that $I\cdot a=0$, where $a=f(1)$. Thus $I\subset\text{ann}(a)$. What should I do next?

Comment: Well, $\varphi$ is just the inclusion of the ideal sheaf. What's your problem in computing $\varphi^{*}$?

Comment: What do you mean by «realizing»? You can do the computation locally, restricting to affines.

Comment: Notice that $\hom_A(A,A)\cong A$ naturally, so that your map is really $a\in A\mapsto(\text{multiplication by $a$})\in\hom_A(I,A)$. That's a more gentle way of looking at it.

Comment: Suppose that $\varphi^*(a)=0$ for some $a\in A$. I need to prove that $a=0$. Suppose $a\neq0$. The condition $\varphi^*(a)=0$ means that $I\subseteq\text{ann}(a)$. What is the contradiction?